# qTip2 shows and hides slowly

Tags: jquery, qtip

In my web app, I have many (sometimes in the 100s) cells that I have a hidden span embedded in like the following:

```
<td class='providerInfo' tabindex=0>
    FIRE DEPARTMENT
    <span class='HIDDEN'>
        Address: New York, NY<br />
        Phone: 123-456-7890<br />
        Type: Facility
    </span>
</td>
```

On page load, I associate a qTip with the hidden span to display it when focusing on the cell that has the info:

```
function loadProviderInfo() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.providerInfo').each(function() {
            $(this).qtip({
                content: {
                    text: function(api) { return $(this).children(".HIDDEN").html(); }
                },
                style: {
                    classes: 'ui-tooltip-blue',
                    def: 'false'
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'bottom left',  // Position my bottom left...
                    at: 'top right', // at the top right of...
                    target: $(this) // my target
                }
            });

            $(this).focusin(function() { $(this).qtip('toggle', true); });
            $(this).focusout(function() { $(this).qtip('toggle', false); });        
        });
    });
}
```

The qTip looks good, but it's showing and hiding really slow.

Any ideas on how to speed up the showing and hiding of the qTip?  I'm OK with even not having any delay on the qTip.

Just needs to work in IE 8.

**Edit 1**
The fewer the cells, the quicker the qTips display.

Answer (score 2):

**Check out**
[Documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#show)

```
hide: { delay: 1000 }
```

> 1000 milliseconds (1 second)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's related more to the event listener than the qTip plugin (though I could be wrong).

My first thought is to try binding the events differently. Why not try jQuery's new `.on()` way of binding listeners? Take the listener out of your `$.each` loop and add it afterwards like so:

```
$('table').on('focusin focusout', '.providerInfo', function(e){
    if(e.type == 'focusin'){
        $(this).qtip('toggle', true);
    }else{
        $(this).qtip('toggle', false);
    }
});
```

Obviously if you have more than one table, use the corresponding class or id of the table in question.

If you have a lot of table cells (like it sounds you do since it slows down more the more you have) this can really lighten the load, binding one event instead of so many.

**Edit** This will only work with jQuery 1.7+ so if you're using an earlier version, I would recommend using `.delegate()` in a similar manner.

Comment: Using jQuery 1.5.2.  I tried the .delegate() method and it shows/hides at about the same rate as using .each

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely with your .each loop, and all of the event listeners (more overhead).

Why not just qTip every .providerInfo element, and use qTips build in events for mouseover and mouseleave?

```
function loadProviderInfo() {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.providerInfo').qtip({
                content: {
                    text: function(api) { return $(this).children(".HIDDEN").html(); }
                },
                style: {
                    classes: 'ui-tooltip-blue',
                    def: 'false'
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'bottom left',  // Position my bottom left...
                    at: 'top right', // at the top right of...
                    target: $(this) // my target
                },
                show: {
                    event: 'mouseenter',
                    target: $(this)
                },
                hide: {
                    event: 'mouseleave',
                    target: $(this)
                }
            });


    });
}
```

I didn't test this code - I was going to do a JSFiddle for you but I couldn't get qTip to include correctly. Just try it out and see if you see any speed increase.

Comment: In my case, using the code snippet you provided freezes up my whole browser.  Not sure exactly what's happening in the background, but IE 8 isn't liking what's going on with this script...

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get to test it. It could fail horribly. I more ment it as an example of what you could do. Go check out the qTip2 documentation on show and hide events, and see if you can conclude your own code from that =).